# How to display entry&exit point in the state transition table

Tags: enterprise-architect, entry-point

At present I have a composite state machine which contains some pseudostates, including initial, exit, choice, entry and exit node. When I use the build-in statechart editor to show the state-next state table, the exit and entry point cannot display as the other pseudostates.

Is there a solution to solve this, so that the **Exitpoint1** can be displayed in the table?

State Machine
[image: State machine]

State Transition table
[image: actual state-next state table]

Comment: I think you have to send a feature request.